# Ajustar dinamicamente un texto en su contenedor aprovechando el mayor tamaño posible

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy trabajando en un nuevo proyecto en Flutter y necesito crear un Widget que basicamente es un Container y un Text centrado dentro de él. 
Pero requiere que el texto siempre ocupe el máximo posible ya sea del ancho o de alto (considerando el que sea menor).
Estoy usando este código pero no es lo que quiero

```
child: Container(
      height: 120,
      width: 100,       
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
      child: Text(
        "90", textAlign:  TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80, color: Colors.blue),
        textScaleFactor: 1,
      ),
    ),
```

[image: Algo asi deseo lograr]

[image: En esta vista se podria aprovechar mas espacio para los numeros]

[image: y en horizontal aun se veran mas pequeños]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona con ese código?

Comment: Como es un widget q se creará como una especia de tablero del 1 al 90 necesito que se ajuste dinamicamente el tamaño al contenedor por que el padre cambiará el alto y el ancho al rotar el dispositivo por ejemplo .

Comment: Ese codigo que puse funciona claramente pero no me ofrece la solucion que necesito. Pondre 2 imagenes mas que ilustran como se veria el widget utilizado en Vertical y en Horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo quita el `fontSize` y `textScaleFactor` que tienes en el `TextStyle` y usa el widget `FittedBox` encima del `Text`.

```dart
Container(
      height: 120,
      width: 100,       
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
      child: FittedBox(
         child: Text(
        "90", textAlign:  TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
       ),
     ),
    )
```

Aquí tienes más info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY

Comment: Perfecto amigo, me han dado en grupo montones de soluciones posibles pero esta creo es la mejor!! Muchas gracias